# Here is a small ORM implemented by Python what's the difference between it and a METACLASS version?

Tags: python, model-view-controller, orm, metaclass

I read some code which implemented a small ORM (Object-relational mapping) without using meatclass, seems it also worked.

So what's the differences between it and a using metaclass version in functional?

If no difference, why metaclass was using in some framework, like Django?

```
' Simple ORM nonuse metaclass V2 '


class Field(object):
    def __init__(self, name, column_type):
        self.name = name
        self.column_type = column_type

    def __str__(self):
        return '<%s:%s>' % (self.__class__.__name__, self.name)


class StringField(Field):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super(StringField, self).__init__(name, 'varchar(100)')


class IntegerField(Field):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super(IntegerField, self).__init__(name, 'bigint')


class Model(dict):
    __db__ = 'db_name'

    def __new__(cls, **kws):

        cls.__table__ = cls.__name__
        cls.__mappings__ = {k: getattr(cls, k) for k in dir(
            cls) if isinstance(getattr(cls, k), Field)}

        return super().__new__(cls, **kws)

    def __init__(self, **kws):
        for k in self.__mappings__.keys():
            setattr(self, k, kws.get(k))

        _kws = {k: v for k, v in kws.items() if k in self.__mappings__.keys()}
        super().__init__(**_kws)

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):

        print('set: ', key, '--->', value)
        if key not in self.__mappings__.keys():
            raise AttributeError(r'unavailable key: %s' % key)
        self[key] = value
        super().__setattr__(key, value)

    def save(self):
        fields = []
        params = []
        args = []
        for k, v in self.__mappings__.items():
            fields.append(v.name)
            params.append('?')
            args.append(getattr(self, k, None))

        sql = 'insert into %s (%s) values (%s)' % (
            self.__table__, ','.join(fields), ','.join(params))
        print('SQL: %s' % sql)
        print('ARGS: %s' % str(args))


class User(Model):

    id = IntegerField('id')
    name = StringField('username')
    email = StringField('email')
    password = StringField('password')


class SubUser(User):

    nickname = StringField('nickname')


if __name__ == '__main__':

    u = User(id=123, name='Michael', email='test@orm.org', password='my-pwd')
    u.save()
```

This small ORM support define class with different Fields, too. So I'm so confused why metaclass is needed.

And the original with metaclass version is [here](https://github.com/michaelliao/awesome-python3-webapp/blob/day-03/www/orm.py).

Comment: Please read about what's on-topic in the [help/on-topic]. Questions here need to be _concrete_. For example, you should be specific about what you mean by "ORM with metaclasses in some frameworks". Please also read [ask].

Comment: Hi, @Chris. Updated question, thanks for your suggestion. I'm learning about using datebase by Python. People use framework like Django to easy coding, ORM means Object-relational mapping. Expected your answer!!

Comment: I know what an ORM is. I'm asking you to provide code from the _specific ORM_ (apparently you mean Django's?) showing how it uses metaclasses. We're not going to go off and dig through the code for you. Make sure to ask a clear, on-topic question.

Comment: (In other words, there are many ORMs out there and they're not all implemented the same way. Be _specific_. What are you asking us to compare against your toy ORM here? Even that may be too broad or opinion-based, so please try to be technical and specific in what you ask.)

Comment: Hi @Chris. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/django/django_models.htm this link shows tow to use Django create a sql table class. And https://github.com/django/django/blob/1ffddfc233e2d5139cc6ec31a4ec6ef70b10f87f/django/db/models/base.py#L399 is the definition of Django model which use metaclass.

Comment: Please include the relevant information _here_, directly in your question as a [mcve]. And, again, be as specific as you can. Please ask an objective question that's on-topic as defined in the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

The code bellow is quote from question's bottom link.

```
        attrs['__select__'] = 'select `%s`, %s from `%s`' % (primaryKey, ', '.join(escaped_fields), tableName)
        attrs['__insert__'] = 'insert into `%s` (%s, `%s`) values (%s)' % (tableName, ', '.join(escaped_fields), primaryKey, create_args_string(len(escaped_fields) + 1))
        attrs['__update__'] = 'update `%s` set %s where `%s`=?' % (tableName, ', '.join(map(lambda f: '`%s`=?' % (mappings.get(f).name or f), fields)), primaryKey)
        attrs['__delete__'] = 'delete from `%s` where `%s`=?' % (tableName, primaryKey)
```

And they will be the attributes of class `User` if using `metaclass`. With out metaclass, they will be attributes of class `User`'s instance. All `User`'s instance have same instance attributes.

So, we should use metaclass and let them just have on copy as class attribute.